# Query with composite key and string_to_array

Tags: postgresql

I want to query both value route and is_deleted.
This is the query i come up with

```
select * 
from route r 
where (r.route, r.is_deleted) = any(string_to_array('ABBEYARD, VICTORIA, AUSTRALIA (CBR), false',';'));
```

But i got error

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: record = text
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add 
explicit type casts.
Position: 53
```

can anyone enlighten me with a proper operator?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want?

Comment: I want to make an equivalent query to this one
```select * from route r where (r.route, r.is_deleted) in (
('ABBEYARD, VICTORIA, AUSTRALIA (CBR)', false),
('ADA, VICTORIA, AUSTRALIA (CBR)', false))```
but using  any(string_to_array())

Comment: Can you understand the idea of my question @YJR

Comment: Can you include the table structure (DDL)?  And explain why "ADA" is included in your comment but not in the original question?  Is that a typo, or do you really mean you want to search those two exact combos?